# bootstrap 2.3.2 elements not aligned right

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have the below html to display in my view.
Its rendering fine in chrome and firefox.
the images are rendered in next line for internet explorer * version

```
<form class="form-search" action="">
<div class="well inline" style="padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;margin-bottom:10px">
    <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText" class="input-xlarge search-query" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
    </div>
    <a class="btn" href="#" style="padding: 4px 6px">Clear</a>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <span class="label label-info inline" style="font-size: 10px">Status :</span>
        <abbr title="Status1">
            <img src="/Content/common/images/check.png" style="width: 16px; height: 16px" alt="Status1" /></abbr>
        <abbr title="Status2">
            <img src="/Content/common/images/x.png" style="width: 16px; height: 16px" alt="Status2" /></abbr>
        <abbr title="Status3">
            <img src="/Content/common/images/y.png" style="width: 16px; height: 16px" alt="Status3" /></abbr>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Attached screenshot below.
[image: See the image below]

Can anyone suggest how to align label and images to right in ie7 and 8 version.

Comment: I guess right padding in pull-right class might be the problem.

Comment: Put them in a list instead? http://jsfiddle.net/NzWzx/

Comment: Tried it, still not working in IE8